# jquery.appear loop through data

Tags: jquery, loops

I am currently using the jquery.appear plugin (https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear/) which is brilliant!

I have an issue, where everytime i add a new element to my page, i have to write a new piece of code for that element. The following has been repeated in my code multiple times, and all that changes is the ID of the element.

```
$('#page2 .wrapper').appear();


$('#page2 .wrapper').on('appear', function(event, $all_appeared_elements) {
     $('#page2n').css('font-weight','bold');
   });

$('#page2 .wrapper').on('disappear', function(event, $all_appeared_elements) {
     $('#page2n').css('font-weight','normal');
   });
```

Is there a more automatic way of doing this? The above will be the same always. I have tried the following, which i had no success with:

```
$( ".screensize" ).each(function() {

  var getid = '#'+$(this).attr('id');
  //alert('#'+$(this).attr('id'));


$(getid+' .wrapper').appear();

$(getid+' .wrapper').on('appear', function(event, $all_appeared_elements) {
     $('#page2n').css('font-weight','bold');
   });

$(getid+' .wrapper').on('disappear', function(event, $all_appeared_elements) {
     $('#page2n').css('font-weight','normal');
   });


});
```

No sure if the above is the right way to approach this?

**EDIT:**

I now have the following code, which only works for one of my elements:

```
 $( ".screensize" ).each(function() {

  var getid = '#'+$(this).attr('id');


$(getid).appear();


$(getid).on('appear', function() {

     $(getid+'n').addClass('active');

});


$(getid).on('disappear', function() {

     $(getid+'n').removeClass('active');

});
```

Removing the disappear function, enables all links to be active, but then obviously they are not removed.

Answer (score 0):

not sure, what is the purpose of ur content. But can you also add a CLASS to all the new ID's taht are appearing.

also, the below code should work:

```
$( ".screensize" ).each(function() {

  var getid = '#'+$(this).attr('id');
  //alert('#'+$(this).attr('id'));


$(getid+' .wrapper').appear();

$(getid+' .wrapper').on('appear', function(event, $all_appeared_elements) {
     $(getid + 'n').css('font-weight','bold');
   });

$(getid+' .wrapper').on('disappear', function(event, $all_appeared_elements) {
     $(getid + 'n').css('font-weight','normal');
   });


});
```

Comment: Thanks i have edited my question, do you no what my problem is now? thanks!

Comment: can u also post ur HTML part. or create a jsfiddle ?